# Can't import other files in same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that when I run it from pycharm, it runs fine, but when executed from the command line it complains

```
import util as u
```

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'`

I followed this advice here:
[Script running in PyCharm but not from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553668/script-running-in-pycharm-but-not-from-the-command-line)

Interpreter is the same, working directory is the same, but sys paths are different.

The module's folder looks like this

```
mymodule
    sub_1
        util.py
    sub_2
         ...
    main.py
```

pycharm shows all folders when printing sys.path elements. when running from the command line, it doesn't show any of them, even when I run it from thr director where `main.py` is.
Do I have to add the directory to `PYTHONPATH` even when I run the file from that directory? Seems like overkill having every project's directory added. Is there a better way to do this or is that the standard procedure?

Comment: try relative `import .util as u`

Comment: make `__init__.py` in `sub_1`

Comment: It seems you don't have a package with subpackages, you have directories containing a bunch of ifles. If `mymodule` was a package, the directory containing it shoud be on `sys.path`, every directory below it should have an `__init__.py` and your shoudn't try call a script inside it. A lounch script should be on the same level as the top level directory and basically just import the entry point and call it.

Comment: thanks digitake. the dot worked its magic. if you could add as reply, I can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

digitake's suggestion to use a relative path worked

```
import .util as u
```

Answer (score 2):

I think more information is needed to make solution recommendations, but here is what I would check for:

1. does your package of modules have the [`__init__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) file(s)
2. when using command line, are you calling python interpreter with the `-I` parameter? that would strip location context from your script and so **not** scan the local directory for modules or packages, so if you do, try running without it.