# Can't import certain package in cmd, but can import it with sublime text3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

So I am trying to import certain packages, when I use this command in cmd, `py test.py`, all I get is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named holidays`

The only thing in `test.py` is `import holidays`.

But when I try to execute `test.py` in sublime text3, it works. No error happens.

I have tried to find the answer by Google, but can's find anything helpful. Please help me. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be linked to what @wim say in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553668/script-running-in-pycharm-but-not-from-the-command-line)

You may want to check some points:

1. Do you use the same python interpreter?

   `import sys; print(sys.executable)`
2. Is this the same current directory that both use?

   `import os; print(os.getcwd())`
3. Check the sys.path, and difference between both could lead to error (can be caused by environment variable).

   `import sys; print(sys.path)`

(This answer is totally based on what Wim said and was accepted on the question from the linked post, if it answer your question please give him credit).

Comment: Thank you! I fix the problem and I will give him credit! Really appreciate your help!