# Fail to import tensorflow from a program called within a script via ssh

Tags: python, tensorflow, ssh

I want to automate hyperparameter search. So I decided to write a python script that automated that task. Basically it (`script.py`) looks like:

```
import os

parameters = [0.001, 0.002, 0.003]

for p in parameters:
    os.system("python main.py --learning_rate={}".format(p))
```

While `main.py` starts with `import tensorflow as tf` and then does its magic.

When I run `$  python main.py --learning_rate=0.001` it does its job without problem (both on my computer and on the server). When I try the script on my computer it works fine BUT when I try to run `$  python script.py` on the server it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                  
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>                 
    import tensorflow as tf                                            
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

This is my first question, please let me know if I should make any changes or add/remove information. Thanks.

Solution:

Thanks for the help! By checking what was suggested in [Script running in PyCharm but not from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553668/script-running-in-pycharm-but-not-from-the-command-line) I was able to spot the problem and solve my error. All I had to do in my script was then to change `os.system("python main.py --learning_rate={}".format(p))` for `os.system("python3.6 main.py --learning_rate={}".format(p))` to get it running.

Comment: In the server did you install tensorflow in system python or another environment such as anaconda/minconda?